# Conversion from string storage ref to bytes memory[] memory

Tags: solidity, hedera-hashgraph

Error:

`Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string storage ref to bytes memory[] memory requested.`

Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./hip-206/HederaTokenService.sol";
import "./hip-206/HederaResponseCodes.sol";

contract Mint is HederaTokenService{

   address tokenAddress
   string public uri = "abc"
 

       function mint(uint64 _amount) external {
       (
           int256 response,
           uint64 newTotalSupply,
       ) = HederaTokenService.mintToken(tokenAddress, _amount, uri);
       if (response != HederaResponseCodes.SUCCESS) {
           revert("Mint Failed");
       }
```

The issue arrises when I try to call the function HederaTokenService.mintToken because it expects the uri to be a bytes memory[] memory. Not sure how to convert it.

The following is the function of mintToken:

```
   /// Mints an amount of the token to the defined treasury account
   /// @param token The token for which to mint tokens. If token does not exist, transaction results in
   ///              INVALID_TOKEN_ID
   /// @param amount Applicable to tokens of type FUNGIBLE_COMMON. The amount to mint to the Treasury Account.
   ///               Amount must be a positive non-zero number represented in the lowest denomination of the
   ///               token. The new supply must be lower than 2^63.
   /// @param metadata Applicable to tokens of type NON_FUNGIBLE_UNIQUE. A list of metadata that are being created.
   ///                 Maximum allowed size of each metadata is 100 bytes
   /// @return responseCode The response code for the status of the request. SUCCESS is 22.
   /// @return newTotalSupply The new supply of tokens. For NFTs it is the total count of NFTs
   /// @return serialNumbers If the token is an NFT the newly generate serial numbers, otherwise empty.
   function mintToken(address token, uint64 amount, bytes[] memory metadata) internal
       returns (int responseCode, uint64 newTotalSupply, int64[] memory serialNumbers)
   {
       (bool success, bytes memory result) = precompileAddress.call(
           abi.encodeWithSelector(IHederaTokenService.mintToken.selector,
           token, amount, metadata));
       (responseCode, newTotalSupply, serialNumbers) =
           success
               ? abi.decode(result, (int32, uint64, int64[]))
               : (HederaResponseCodes.UNKNOWN, 0, new int64[](0));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just casting it works for me:

```
bytes memory var = bytes(<storage string>);
```